# ASP Create own Update Statement in sqlDataSource

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I am trying to make own update using graphic interface in VisualStudio but my update dont work.

When i test it in query builder everything works but when i run the web page after click update added to grid it's restore to previous state because the update did nothing.

`Params("ID,IsCompleted")` are added to `DataKeyNames` in Property in GridView.
Unfortunately I could not find any solutions using a graphical interface.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

subscribe SqlDataSource's OnUpdated event, check AffectedRows value. 
ref msdn [SqlDataSource.UpdateCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updatecommand(v=vs.110).aspx) 
codes

```
private void OnDSUpdatedHandler(Object source, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) {
    if (e.AffectedRows > 0) {
        // Perform any additional processing, 
        // such as setting a status label after the operation.
        Label1.Text = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name +
            " changed user information successfully!";    
    }
    else {
        Label1.Text = "No data updated!";
    }
 }
```

aspx

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
  id="SqlDataSource1"
  runat="server"
  DataSourceMode="DataSet"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Title FROM Employees"
  UpdateCommand="Update Employees SET FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,Title=@Title WHERE EmployeeID=@EmployeeID"
  OnUpdated="OnDSUpdatedHandler">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView
  id="GridView1"
  runat="server"
  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
  DataKeyNames="EmployeeID"
  AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  <columns>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="FirstName" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="LastName" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Title" DataField="Title" />
  </columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Label
  id="Label1"
  runat="server">
</asp:Label>
```

other ref [SqlDataSourceView.OnUpdating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourceview.onupdating(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, I receives information in label " serverName/User changed user information successfully!" but still did not change the record in the database.

Comment: could you use sql profiler to look what's sql or check ConnectionString name MyNorthwind in web.config.